# Newbie silverlight question: Passing parameter to usercontrol

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik

let's say i have the following  usercontrol :

```
<UserControl x:Class="TVPage.SilverlightControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Name="myTxt" Margin="125,107,115,147" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'd like to show this usercontrol inside of a telerik radWindow by setting the mytxt text from another form. I just start the silverlight, and trying to understand the basic and would appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the value you want in the text box in to the constructor of the user control when you create it on the main window.

Comment: +1: If you were passing parameters from the ASPX page, then I would use `InitParameters`.